# How to apply client side validation on rich text editor?

Tags: .net, validation, rich-text-editor

I have a tinymce rich text editor on my aspx apge(.net), I want to apply client side validation on this. Can anybody help me?

Comment: did you try to add validation on text area? (btw i prefer ckEditor on my projects)

Comment: I have been trying to fetch the value of text area as "alert(document.getElementById('<%=txt_editor1.ClientID %>').value);" but it shows me an empty alert, What could be the possible cause of the problem?

Comment: try tinyMCE.get('<%=txt_editor1.ClientID %>').getContent or tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent

Comment: can i see what you are trying to do?

Comment: if (document.getElementById('<%=txt_Fname1.ClientID %>').value =="") 
   alert('Please Enter value');

Comment: how u are calling this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34597/discussion-between-shilpa-soni-and-arda-chapuler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `tinyMCE.get('<%=txt_editor1.ClientID %>').getContent()` instead of `document.getElementById('<%=txt_editor1.ClientID %>').value` so you could achieve like this.

```
function valid(){
  var content = tinyMCE.get('<%=txt_editor1.ClientID %>').getContent();
  if(content.length>100){
  return false;
  }
  return true;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have Html editor tinymce the required validation is not working ok, you can use this code to solve your problem,
install tinymce in your application

**In model** give the path of tinymce.cshtml page ok

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter About Company")]
    [Display(Name = "About Company : ")]
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string txtAboutCompany { get; set; }
```

Now in your view add one span like this

```
 <div class="divclass">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany, new { @class = "required" })
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany)
     <span class="field-validation-error" id="AC" style="margin:9px 0 0 157px;"></span>
 </div>
```

Create jQuery on submit button click event

```
$("#BusinessProfile").click(function () {
        var aboutC = $("#txtAboutCompany").val()
        var pinfo = $("#txtProductinfo").val();
        if (aboutC == "" && pinfo == "") {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
            $("#bpform").valid();
            return false;
        } else if (aboutC == "") {
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("")
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
            $("#txtAboutCompany").focus();
            $("#bpform").valid();
            return false;
        } else if (pinfo == "") {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("")
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
            $("#txtProductinfo").focus();
            $("#bpform").valid();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("");
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("");
            //return true;
            $("#bpform").validate();
        }
    });
```

i hope your problem may be solve